# python script- no error but no result and output is an empty file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the following code to filter a txt file based on the info in 89,90,91 and 92 index.
The problem is that output file is an empty file just with headers.The code is not giving any error-so am not sure how else to go about debugging it.
Thanks for helping!!

```
    for line in fileHandle: 
        if firstLineFlag == 0:  #to skip first line
            firstLineFlag = 1
            firstLineText = line    #save the first line elsewhere
            continue
        parts = line.strip().split('\t')

                        try:
                            column13=float(parts[13-1])
                        except ValueError:
                            column13=0
                        if column13 < 0.01:

                            if parts[92] == "./.:.:.:.:.":
                                Nor_info_2 = parts[92].replace("./.:.:.:.:.", "00:1,1:1:1:1,1,1")

                            if parts[91] == "./.:.:.:.:.":
                                Nor_info = parts[91].replace("./.:.:.:.:.", "00:1,1:1:1:1,1,1")

                            if parts[90] == "./.:.:.:.:.":
                                Tu_info_2 = parts[90].replace("./.:.:.:.:.", "00:1,1:1:1:1,1,1")

                            if parts[89] == "./.:.:.:.:.":
                                Tu_info = parts[89].replace("./.:.:.:.:.", "00:1,1:1:1:1,1,1")

                                normalSplit_2 = parts[92].split(':')
                                normalSplit = parts[91].split(':')
                                tumorSplit_2 = parts[90].split(':')
                                tumorSplit = parts[89].split(':')

                                print(Nor_info_2)
                                try:
                                    TD_Tumor_2 = float(tumorSplit_2[3-1])
                                except ValueError:
                                    TD_Tumor = 0    

                                    try:
                                        TD_Tumor = float(tumorSplit[3-1])
                                    except ValueError:
                                        TD_Tumor = 0

                                try:
                                    TD_Normal_2 = float(normalSplit_2[3-1])
                                except ValueError:
                                    TD_Tumor = 0    

                                    try:
                                        TD_Normal = float(normalSplit[3-1])
                                    except ValueError:
                                        TD_Tumor = 0

                                    if TD_Tumor_2 >= TD_Tumor and TD_Tumor_2 >= 7:
                                        tumorAD=tumorSplit_2[2-1].split(',')
                                        normalAD=normalSplit_2[2-1].split(',')
                                        normalratio=float(normalAD[2-1])/TD_Normal_2
                                    else:
                                        tumorAD=tumorSplit[2-1].split(',')
                                        normalAD=normalSplit[2-1].split(',')
                                        normalratio=float(normalAD[2-1])/TD_Normal

                                        tumorratio=float(tumorAD[2-1])/TD_Tumor_2

                                        parts.append(tumorratio)
                                        parts.append(normalratio)
                                        data.append(parts)
```

dataz1 = sorted(data, key = itemgetter(91), reverse = True)

```
#with open('filtered/'+currentFile+'_filtered.txt', 'w') as fileHandle:         ## to write your data in proper format
with open(currentFile+'_filtered.txt', 'w') as fileHandle:          ## to write your data in proper format
    fileHandle.write(firstLineText) 
    for item in data:
        convert_first_to_generator = (str(w) for w in item)
        string =  '\t'.join(convert_first_to_generator)
        string += '\n'
        #print string
        fileHandle.write(string)

command = 'mv '+currentFile+'_filtered.txt  filtered/'      ### to move edited files into a different folder
system(command)
```

Comment: You said something about an output file but I don't see anything of the sort in the code. For debugging I suggest flooding your code with print statements Particularly in the if statements to ensure it gets reached. Something like `print( lineNumber, lineText )`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I did try to print blocks and errors...but for some reason even print(variable names) is not working. Meaning-is giving me empty result files...here is the snippet from the code that I used to generate the output file..Also I just added the snippet of code that I used to generate the out file...I apologise for it not being the best and being too verbose...I will appreciate if folks could help me get it more precise and succint

Comment: Is the indentation for the code post correct? Because the indentation following `if parts[89]` doesn't look right. Otherwise I suggest starting from scratch and printing as you go ensuring that each line works and what you do is what you expect to happen.

Comment: Thanks Steven...it took me some time I was able to sort it out printing different sections of the block...